# Where to put data access methods in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My question is that where should I put data access methods  in an ASP.NET MVC project?

(by data access methods I mean the methods which execute CRUD statements)

as I've heard we should write CRUD statements (using Entity framework actually) in each controller directly. Is that right? if not what is the right way?

Comment: it would help if you post an example of one of the methods that you have created to get additional feedback.

Comment: No, never in the controller. Have you heard of separation of concerns? That's not a controller's job. Data access doesn't belong in an MVC project at all. Put it in a separate class library, then reference that class library from your MVC project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with injecting `DbContext` to controller. However, if some CRUD queries use elsewhere, then you'll end up with repeated codes.

I *personally* prefer calling ***Repository Layer*** instead of Presentation Layer (controllers and action methods) directly accessing `DbContext`. By doing so, you ***Unit Test*** those repository CRUD methods.

For example, in my sample project at GitHub, I create [`UserRepository`](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Repositories/Users/UserRepository.cs#L11), and inject [`IUserRepository`](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Repositories/Users/IUserRepository.cs#L7) to [`UserController`](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L39). I then implement [`UserServiceTests`](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Tests/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Services.Tests/Users/UserServiceTests.cs#L16) to unit test those methods. If you want to go further, you could implement `Generic Repository`.